# How to cache Methods for one process?

Tags: php, oop

I'm trying to cache an Object's method, so every time I call the Class and the method, it won't process again after first time.

Here is what I'm trying to achieve,

```
class App {
    public $data = null;

    public function print() {
        if ( $this->data === null ) {
            $this->data = "First time.";
        }
        else {
            $this->data = "After first time.";
        }
        return $this->data;
    }
}

$data = new App();
echo $data->print() . "<br>";
echo $data->print() . "<br>";

$data2 = new App();
echo $data2->print() . "<br>";
echo $data2->print() . "<br>";
```

**Result**

```
First time.
After first time.
First time.
After first time.
```

As you can see, it's processing the print() method again when I call it again in $data2.

Is it possible to cache so result will be

```
First time.
After first time.
After first time.
After first time.
```

Comment: If you want that, keep using `$data` and don't make a new instance of the class. Each instance of a class is _intentionally_ separate, so you can treat them differently (e.g. you could have multiple instances of an `Employee` class which could form a list of employees, and each would you would want to print different data for it - that would be a _good_ thing).

Comment: Or, if you want a variable which is held in common between all instances of a class (which are otherwise separate) you can consider using a static variable and/or function.

Comment: Great help @ADyson! Now I understand static and non-static method correctly.

Answer (score 1):

For get your required constant output you need to

> change the public variable inside the class to as static variable

Because public static variables share all the available instances of that class each time.

```
class App {
    public static $data = null;

    public function print() {
        if ( self::$data === null ) {
            self::$data = "First time.";
        }
        else {
            self::$data = "After first time.";
        }
        return self::$data;
    }
}

$data = new App();
echo $data->print() . "<br>";
echo $data->print() . "<br>";

$data2 = new App();
echo $data2->print() . "<br>";
echo $data2->print() . "<br>";
```

**Result will be :**

```
First time.
After first time.
After first time.
After first time.
```